# Multiplying a array times 2

Tags: java, arrays

In the last method, computeTwice, I am trying to multiply the array that is inputed by 2, but instead of doing that it is listing the array in least to greatest order. Can someone please help me fix that issue.

Code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numbers[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        numbers[i] = console.nextInt();
        }
    printReverse(numbers); 
    getLargest(numbers);
    computeTwice(numbers);
    }

public static void printReverse(int [] numbers) { 
  int [] revNumbers = new int[numbers.length];
  for(int i = numbers.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    revNumbers[numbers.length - 1 -i] = numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Here are you numbers in reverse: "+Arrays.toString(revNumbers));
    }

public static int getLargest(int [] numbers){ 
int max = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){ 
  if(numbers[i] > max) { 
    max = numbers[i];
    }
  }
    System.out.println("The highest number is: "+max); 
    Arrays.sort(numbers); 
    return max;
    }


public static int[] computeTwice(int[] numbers){
    for (int i = 0; i > numbers.length; i++){ 
        numbers[i] *= 2;
    }
    System.out.println("The array with two times the numbers: "+ Arrays.toString(numbers));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time put a stack trace, since there is an error.

```
public static int[] computeTwice(int[] numbers){
    for (int i = 0; i > numbers.length; i++){ 
        numbers[i] *= 2;
    }
    System.out.println("The array with two times the numbers: "+ Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

How can i, the index of the array you are targeting, be greater than the length? Perhaps you meant

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void computeTwice(int[] numbers){
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){ 
        numbers[i] *= 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One little error in your for loop. Look at your conditions. You initialized it correctly (i = 0), incremented it correctly (i++), but your condition is incorrect (i > numbers.length). You need to change it to 
                (i < numbers.length)

Also, when you create a method with a value type, you need to return that data type, otherwise create your method header with "void".

Since you created your method with the int[] value type, you need to return your int[], like so:

```
    public static int[] computeTwice(int[] numbers) {

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { //note the condition change
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;
    }
    System.out.println("The array with two times the numbers: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
    return numbers; //note the change by adding a return statement
}
```

}

Comment: thanks this made it perfect